# QT GUI Development along freeglut renderer

Tags: qt, opengl, renderer, freeglut

for the past few weeks I've been developing custom renderer with freeglut and glew using `VS 2010 Express`, this renderer will be a part 3d editing tool.

Now the time came to pick a right `GUI toolkit`, I went for `QT` having heard all the good stuff about it.

The problem is that I have just discovered that `QT` uses it own `OpenGl` calls and handles **mouse/keyboard events** in it own way.

Does that mean I would have to rewrite large portion of my rendering calls as well as all my **mouse/keyboard callbacks** using `QT library` just to be able to use it as my tool's main `GUI` Framework?

Perhaps there is a smarter way to make them two work together that I am not aware of ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Qt instead of registering callbacks you're deriving from *QGLWidget* and override the mouse and keyboard event handler functions (inherited from *QWidget*). The changes to your input event handling are minimal.

*QGLWidget::resizeGL* is much like the reshape callback and *QGLWidget::paintGL* much like the display callback.

> The problem is that I have just discovered that QT uses it own OpenGl calls

They're provided as a convenience. You can use GLEW and your regular OpenGL calls just fine with Qt. Most importantly you must make sure to include *glew.h* before any Qt header in all relevant compilation units and the headers those use.

Comment: Amazing , I just had a go at it and it work's like a charm ! The only thing that I'll have to tweak is the input events but that's a small price to pay, and all my rendering code stay's intact. Thanks !!